# Building iPhone Quiz App

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, random, plist

I am attempting to make a quiz app for the iPhone.  I don't quite know about how to start it.  There will be hundreds of questions, so I don't want to have to build a separate view for each one.  What format should I import the questions into the app to read, and then set it up to do questions in random order, and by category (i.e. all questions at once, only math questions, only english questions, etc.)?

Comment: I just published mine recently on http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ntqz/ - I build custom quizzes too. PM me if you are still looking for a solution or I could be of any help. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There will be hundreds of questions, so I don't want to have to build
>   a separate view for each one.

Of course not. Think of the questions as the data that the app operates on. You might want one view for each question format, e.g. multiple choice, short answer, etc.

> What format should I import the questions into the app to read

That's totally up to you -- it's a design decision, so choose whatever works best for you. When faced with an arbitrary-seeming decision like this, it's often a good idea to stay flexible. For example, you might decide to put the questions in a text file for now, but design your code so that it's easy to plug code that reads a different format.

> and then set it up to do questions in random order, and by category
>   (i.e. all questions at once, only math questions, only english
>   questions, etc.)?

Sounds like you might want to consider storing the questions in some sort of database. You can then query the database with different criteria to get different sets of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the questions using CoreData and then read them from a JSON file or something similar when the app loads for the first time. This would also allow you to update the questions via a REST api in the future.

You could take a look at [RestKit](http://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) which would take care of a lot of the parsing for you.

After you have all the questions loaded up into your database the rest is up to you, but its quite easy to build a view on top of CoreDate.

Comment: your answer is similar to one of the App I am working now. I have json file hosted in my website that contains the questions/answers of my Quiz App. The problem is, my App is too slow reading directly from the URL. I want to store the whole json file into my application when the App runs for the first time and then read from inside the App. I do not have much knowledge in core data but I am guessing that this can solve my problem. Do you know any tutorial about this?

Comment: If you take a look at the RestKit documentation it will show you how to load your JSON into core data. Once you have it there you can take a look at the master detail application that is created when you start a new project. It should show you the basics of core data. From there Apple has a lot of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend organizing your questions in a database, something like this for example:

```
Questions Table
QuestionID | Question                          | Answer       | Category
1          | What is 2 + 2                     | 5            | math
2          | What is the capital of Argentina? | Buenos Aires | geography
```

This way it would be simple to use a single view and access the questions with SQL.

Comment: How would one setup the database?  Like what program could I use to do this?  I have all the questions currently in a RTF file.  I'm guessing, just have an area for incorrect answers, then a category for the correct one?

Comment: I'm sure you could use a simple text editor on your RTF to automate creating the `INSERT` SQL statements. Then it would just be a matter of running the commands against a database engine. Firefox has an extension called [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) that would work well for this sort of task.

Comment: If you're not interested in going this route, maybe you could just keep all of your questions in RAM?

Comment: Setting up a database isn't something you typically 'do with a program'. I would check out http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/ for a tutorial of sqlite databases for ios.